# Custom entity with existing data

Tags: 7, entities, chaos-tool-suite

I'm looking into creating a Drupal 7 custom entity for panels pages created with ctools Page Manager, in order to index this content with the [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api). An existing project, [Page Manager Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager_search), seems to be doing just that, but I'm hitting [an issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager_search/issues/2810379) where an exception thrown when attempting to index. So I wanted to better understand the process, and whether or not it's recommended / feasible to build a custom entity off of existing data.

From what I've seen in the Page Manager Search project, it looks like it's maybe possible to create a custom entity without using `hook_schema()`. Anyone have any experience doing so, and any potential pitfalls?